# Why do I receive a PermissionError: [WinError 5] when installing pip as a administrator?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pip

I'm facing this issue while trying to install pip using Python 3.6.

[image: permission error]

I receive the message "Access is denied" from a user folder, but Python 3.6 is in the windows folder.  Do I need to be in a virtual environment to install the pip update?

Comment: Its likely whatever path you have pip pointing to, you don't have access

Comment: I can't see an "attached image of the issue". Anyway: try `python.exe -m pip install -U pip`. If this doesn't work, execute `pip show pip`. Does it show _Version: 10.0.1_? I think to remember that there was an issue with an older version of _pip_.

Comment: Now I am sure I faced the same problem. As far as I remember, I uninstalled _pip_ and installed the latest version from [Python Package Index (PyPI)](https://pypi.org/project/pip/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 and pip upgrading - Access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126940/windows-10-and-pip-upgrading-access-denied)

Comment: It's a Windows limitation. `pip.exe` file is in use and thus locked and can't be deleted. Use `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: Thanks! The pip I have is the latest version (10.0.1).  I used the python -m pip install --upgrade pip, and received a message of "requirement already up-to-date: ..."

Answer (score 0):

Run the anaconda prompt as administrator:

```
pip install --user --upgrade pip
```

It should help.