# Python 3.7 - PIP upgrade error on windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, installation

I tried to update PIP (Windows 10, Python 3.7.1) in console using command:

```
python37 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

This is an error I got everytime I try to update it:

```
>Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\5gyblo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\5gyblo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\Users\5gyblo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Users\5gyblo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "C:\Users\5gyblo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "C:\Users\5gyblo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 462, in move_wheel_files
    generated.extend(maker.make(spec))
  File "C:\Users\5gyblo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 372, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\5gyblo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 276, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "C:\Users\5gyblo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 212, in _write_script
    launcher = self._get_launcher('t')
  File "C:\Users\5gyblo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 351, in _get_launcher
    result = finder(distlib_package).find(name).bytes
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bytes'
```

Surprising fact - I had succesfully updated PIP on Python 2.7 isntance without any problems.

Comment: Have you tried just upgrading from pip directly a la `pip install --upgrade pip`? What happens?

Comment: @Idlehands It's impossible to upgrade pip with pip in Windows because damn Windows locks currently running process `pip.exe` and doesn't allow to overwrite it.

Comment: @phd odd, I actually upgraded `pip` directly a few times with the exact command without issues.  Could it be Windows version? Seems to work fine on Windows 7.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32129897/7976758

Comment: I have tried `pip install --upgrade pip` (the result is pretty much the same from what you see above).
I have checked and it looks the problem between windows 10 and Python 3.*.
I was able to install older version of pip (10.*) for python 3.*. I do not have any problems with Python 2.* though. It is compatibility issue that have not been solved so far (from what I see).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I faced this error while trying to upgrade from pip version 18.1 to 19.0.3.
After a lot of search I hit the solution at https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/
(If that still doesn’t allow you to run pip:

Securely Download get-pip.py [1]

Run python get-pip.py. [2] This will install or upgrade pip. Additionally, it will install setuptools and wheel if they’re not installed already.)

The link there takes you to:

Use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Download and save the file, run it from command prompt. It worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Secure download worked for me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried many other solutions and this one eventually resolves the issue!

Comment: Thank you, you're a lifesaver--this is the only solution that has fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I got the same result :(.

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem of pip going into a constant downward loop of installing all of it's previous versions. Annoying as hell!