# `pip install --upgrade pip` fails inside a Windows virtualenv with "Access denied"

Tags: python, windows, pip, virtualenv

On Windows, if you try to use `pip` to upgrade itself, inside a virtualenv, you may get a mysterious "access is denied" error.  For instance:

```
D:\scratch\> C:\Program Files\Python\3.7.4\x64\python.exe -m venv D:\scratch\my-venv
D:\scratch\> D:\scratch\my-venv\Scripts\activate
(my-venv) D:\scratch\> pip install --upgrade pip

Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-19.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.0.3
    Uninstalling pip-19.0.3:
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 
  [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'd:\\scratch\\my-venv\\scripts\\pip.exe'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

This happens whether or not the command prompt has administrative privileges.
We know we have write access to everything inside `d:\scratch\my-venv`, because we just created it with the initial `python -m venv` command.  The advice to use the `--user` option is unhelpful, since we want to upgrade the version of pip *inside the virtualenv*, which `--user` will not do.

What could be wrong, and what is the correct way to upgrade pip inside a virtualenv on Windows?

Comment: Have you tried running administrator command prompt?

Comment: @EcSync Yes, the exact same thing happens whether or not the command prompt is elevated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 and pip upgrading - Access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126940/windows-10-and-pip-upgrading-access-denied)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%5Bwindows%5D+upgrade+Access+denied

Comment: @phd That's nice and all but that earlier Q&A completely failed to come up in multiple searches, and it has also attracted incorrect answers (administrative privileges absolutely do not help in the scenario I'm talking about).  I wrote this one to fix the google juice on this problem, basically.

Answer (score 28):

I don't know if this is the *only* reason this can happen, but notice that the "Access is denied" error points at `d:\scratch\my-venv\scripts\pip.exe`.  pip is trying to replace *itself*, and Windows doesn't allow you to modify a running EXE file in any way.

A workaround for this specific problem is to use `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` instead.  This way, `pip.exe` is not running, so Windows will allow it to be replaced.  This action doesn't try to overwrite `d:\scratch\my-venv\scripts\python.exe`, and Windows doesn't care what pip does to all the other files belonging to the pip package.

See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/188 and https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1299 for further information.

Comment: Thanks. As suggested, running `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` does work. It would be a REALLY good idea for somebody to add a check. It is so easy to have the venv not having pip at all. Uninstall succeeds, install doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You must have the same version of `pip` installed in windows as in the virtual env. I think that is the reason for the error `Access Denied` in Virtual Env.

in promt,

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

located in the Scripts folder of the virtual env, execute the update command  [upgrade pip in venv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xkdka.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I would have put this in a comment to zwol's answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

I just wanted to add to anyone else potentially coming across this from google like I did, that `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` did fix this issue for me. However if you try `pip install --upgrade pip` before doing that, something happens in the process before you hit the access denied error that messes up pip. I personally was getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'` after trying to upgrade the normal way.

Once I deleted and restarted my `virtualenv` and had the first command be `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` It worked just fine.

I hope that helps other newbies out there struggling like me! :)

Answer (score 0):

Same error for me, but in both conditions: my system pip and virtualenv pip. So, when I tried to upgrade my system pip, hopefully it wasn't like totally deleted, I could still use the "pip" command. However I know the upgrade system pip failed. When I tried the command again, it said pip was on the **latest version**. Maybe this is just a glitch. I believe it is the same for virtual environments(virtualenv, venv). When I upgrade the system pip I get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\heewo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-8ob_krif\\pip.exe'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I know this is not normal. But still, different than the virtualenv, "pip" is still installed. I believe this is still ignorable as this is just a known issue and most people here know about this topic. For me, `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` did not work in this state.
I tried this method, and this did work for me.

```
virtualenv --pip [VERSION]
```

and replace `VERSION` with the latest version available on pip. This prints out that what version you are attempting to upgrade to, when you get the error.
And that should do the trick.